# How to debug request-promise MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, events, http-post, httprequest

I've been working on a set-up script for a database and this evening I began getting some MaxListenersExceededWarning warnings in my console.
[image: warnings image with log output]

I debugged the warnings to be coming from specific request-promise-native calls. I initially thought it may have something to do with payload size; however this warning is not happening on the largest request. I'm really lost on how to debug this further and get to the bottom of these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what I was doing wrong:

I am using a logger called pino in my application. For a lot of my set up methods I had an optional logger parameter that defaults to a stdout instance of pino when undefined. This default behavior was creating multiple writestreams hence the MaxListeners warning. I changed my code to pass the same stdout logger instance to all methods and now there are no more warnings!